# send / receive id view to controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Functionality is ok, now I need to work with ajax like submit form without page loading.

This is my work below:

view:

```
<%= form_for :accept, url: accept_path(:id => applicants.id), action: :accept, method: :put  do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :accept, :value => '1' %>
  <div id="acc" class="btn btn-success">Accept</div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def accept
    @accpt = Apply.find(params[:id])
    if @accpt.update_attributes(accept_params)
      flash[:success] = "Accepted"
      #redirect_to home_path
    else
      render 'accept'
    end
end
```

Ajax:

```
script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on("click", '#acc', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "accept",
      type: "PUT",
      dataType: "json",
      data: { id: $(this).id },
      complete: function() {},
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        editor.setValue(data.file_content)
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Ajax error!")
     }
  });
 });
</script>
```

routes

```
put 'accept/:id' => 'applicants#accept', as: :accept
```

Now showing ajax error.

How can I reach solution?

Comment: Error is : `Couldn't find Apply with 'id'=id`, but without ajax work properly, problem is page loading

Comment: add `:remote=>true` in form

Comment: No any effect  after implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change this to use the core Rails AJAX functionality - Rails has removed all of that complexity in your JS when dealing with AJAX:

Get rid of all the custom AJAX javascript you posted.

View:

```
<%= form_for :accept, url: accept_path(:id => applicants.id), action: :accept, method: :put, remote: true  do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :accept, :value => '1' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Accept', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def accept
    @accpt = Apply.find(params[:id])
    if @accpt.update_attributes(accept_params)
      render 'accept'
    else
      render 'error'
    end
end
```

Add an accept.js file in /views/controller_name/ with:

```
editor.setValue(data.file_content)
```

Add an error.js file in /views/controller_name/ with:

```
//code for update failed
```

Comment: I'm actually don't understanding what you said

Comment: Rails allows you to use AJAX as part of the default package. Trying reading this article that might explain it more: http://www.korenlc.com/remote-true-in-rails-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="acc" class="btn btn-success" data-applicant=<%= applicants.id %>>Accept</div>
```

and

```
data: { id: $(this).data("applicant")},
```